# node.js multiple initialization of library is fine?

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js with libraries like winston, mongodb and etc. I split nodejs to multiple files for easy maintenance like index.js, user.js, posting.js, database.js, logging.js, and etc.

logging.js is like below:

```
var config = require('./config'),     
path = require ('path'),
winston = require('winston'),
winstonRotate = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

winston.level = config.appSetting.winstonLogLevel;

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),  
    new (winstonRotate)({
      name: 'info-file',
      datePattern: '.yyyyMMdd',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "logs", "info.log"),    
      level: 'info'
    }),
    new (winstonRotate)({
      name: 'error-file',
      datePattern: '.yyyyMMdd',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "logs", "error.log"),    
      level: 'error'
    }),
    new (winstonRotate)({
      name: 'debug-file',
      datePattern: '.yyyyMMdd',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "logs", "debug.log"),    
      level: 'debug'
    }),
    new (winstonRotate)({
      name: 'warn-file',
      datePattern: '.yyyyMMdd',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "logs", "warn.log"),    
      level: 'warn'
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

database.js

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,    
mongodbObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
logger = require('./logging'), database;

// Connect to the db
mongoClient.connect(config.appSetting.dbConnectionString, function(err, db) {

  if(!err) {

    database = db;

    logger.info("Connected to DB");

  } else {

     logger.error("Failed to connect to moolahome mongodb : " + err);

     console.dir(err);

     process.exit(1);       
  }

});

module.exports = database;
```

I add logging.js to index.js, user.js and posting.js and database.js for logging and this lead to 4 times initialization of logger. 
I add database.js to index.js, user.js and posting.js nd this lead to 3 times initialization of database.

Is this ok or need to make logger and database to singleton?

Answer (score 0):

All libraries (or modules) are cached in `require` object after first load.
[Check this out](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).
So, it's ok for runtime and sure it's your own decision about app structure :)